# Django: Null field with managed=False

Tags: python, django, django-models, nullable

When a model is not managed by Django, does it matter what the value of `null` on a field is?

Comment: In the model, if you have null=True, then the field can have null or be left blank in a form. If set to False, then the field has to be filled with something other than NULL

Comment: @Luke: That sure sounds like an answer.  Please post it as an answer with a link to the Django documentation.  That way we can vote on it properly.

Comment: @Luke: Really? I thought you still need `blank` for the field to be left blank in a form...

Comment: Sorry, if you want it to hold empty strings, then blank needs to be set to true. It defaults to false. my bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[managed=False](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#managed) no database table creation or deletion operations will be performed for this model. So, Your field is null or not null does not reflect through your code written in `models.py`

Answer (score 1):

In the model, if you have null=True, then the field can have null or be left blank in a form. If set to False, then the field has to be filled with something other than NULL

Found here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/models/fields/#null